# routing issue with Sonata admin news post in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

Getting an error trying to set up the Sonata Admin bundle, get the following error when I got to http://localhost:8000/admin/dashboard, not sure how to solve this? Thanks!

**Error**
     An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "admin_sonata_news_post_create" as such route does not exist.

**This is my appKernal.php file**

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel {
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),
        new Sonata\NewsBundle\SonataNewsBundle(),
        new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle(),
        new Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
        new Sonata\FormatterBundle\SonataFormatterBundle(),
        new Sonata\ClassificationBundle\SonataClassificationBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\KnpMarkdownBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
        new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
        new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle(),
        new Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\ApplicationSonataNewsBundle(),
        new Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle(),
        new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle()
    );
```

**Config_dev.yml**

```
 imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: sonata_news.yml }
- { resource: sonata_classification.yml }
- { resource: sonata_media.yml }
- { resource: sonata_formatter.yml }

 framework:
#esi:             ~
translator:      { fallbacks: "%locale%" }
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_hosts:   ~
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id:  ~
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
#Sonata with Symfony >= 2.6
form_themes:
   - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'

    #Sonata with Symfony <=2.5
    #form:
    #    resources:
    #        - 'SonataFormatterBundle:Form:formatter.html.twig'
  sonata_formatter:
formatters:
    markdown:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.markdown
        extensions:
            - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
            - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
            - sonata.media.formatter.twig #keep this commented unless you are using media bundle.


    text:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.text
        extensions:
            - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
            - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
            - sonata.media.formatter.twig


    rawhtml:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
        extensions:
            - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
            - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
            - sonata.media.formatter.twig


    richhtml:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
        extensions:
            - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
            - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
            - sonata.media.formatter.twig


    twig:
        service: sonata.formatter.text.twigengine
        extensions: [] # Twig formatter cannot have extensions


# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: "%kernel.debug%"
bundles:        [intomusiceventsBundle,intomusicfestivalBundle]

#node: /usr/bin/node

filters:
    uglifyjs2:
        # the path to the uglifyjs executable
        bin: /usr/bin/uglifyjs
    #uglifycss:
       # bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifycss
    #cssrewrite:
      #  apply_to: "\.css$"
#java: /usr/bin/java


  # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:

dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    types:
        json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in  parameters.yml
    # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    # path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
  #  auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
   entity_managers:
        default:
           #naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
          auto_mapping: true
          mappings:
            SonataNewsBundle: ~
            SonataMediaBundle: ~
            SonataClassificationBundle: ~



 sonata_media:
 # if you don't use default namespace configuration
 #class:
 #    media:        MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
 #    gallery:      MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery
 #    gallery_item: MyVendor\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryItem
       db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr   it is     mandatory to choose one here
 default_context: default # you need to set a context
 contexts:
     default:  # the default context is mandatory
         providers:
             - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
             - sonata.media.provider.youtube
             - sonata.media.provider.image
             - sonata.media.provider.file
             - sonata.media.provider.vimeo

         formats:
             small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
             big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

 cdn:
     server:
         path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

 filesystem:
     local:
         directory:  "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media"
         create:     false


sonata_block:
default_contexts: [cms]
blocks:
    # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
            sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
               contexts: [admin]


# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and   'propel'
firewall_name: secured_area
user_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
group:
   group_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

**routing.yml file**

```
 gallery:
resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/gallery.xml'
prefix: /media/gallery

 media:
resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/media.xml'
prefix: /media

news:
resource: '@SonataNewsBundle/Resources/config/routing/news.xml'
prefix: /news

admin_area:
resource:    "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
prefix: /admin
```

Comment: did you tried clear cache?

Comment: Yes I did, no change

Answer (score 1):

Found that I needed to add ApplicaqtionSonataUserBundle as below

```
orm:
 #  auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
 entity_managers:
    default:
       #naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
      auto_mapping: true
      mappings:
        ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
        SonataNewsBundle: ~
        SonataMediaBundle: ~
        SonataClassificationBundle: ~
```

Then routing more routing

```
    fos_user_security:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

 fos_user_profile:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
resource:  
"@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
 prefix: /change-password

 admin:
 resource: 
'@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
resource: .
type: sonata_admin
prefix: /admin

 sonata_user:
 resource:  
  '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
prefix: /admin

sonata_user_impersonating:
pattern: /
defaults: { _controller: SonataPageBundle:Page:catchAll }
```

Then clear the cache, now I get an admin panel but more errors trying to post anything ;( would've been quicker to write my own blog bundle

Comment: also add this to config.yml    - ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: 
    configs:
        news:
            toolbar:      standard

Comment: Routing AND CLEARING THE CACHE seems to be the most important, at least with Sf 4.4